# Methods that work individually for multiple elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, methods

I can't find a good guide on this, but what I'm looking for here is just a push in the right direction.

Lets say I have defined a new method

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'myMethod', {
    enumerable : false,
    configurable: true,
    value : function(args) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.doThis = function () {
            // some functionality
        }

        ....

        return this
});
```

The code inside will work for let's say $('#element'), but if I apply the method to $('.elements') it will only work for the first element of the array. How do I rewrite the method to be applicable to both single elements and groups of elements?

***EDIT*** ************************************

*So I've gotten a hint that, when jQuery is available I would use jQuery.fn.extend(), but my concern is - can the approach from above be rewritten so it works for multiple elements of the same class?*

Comment: wait, are you writing a jQuery plugin, or an extension on the vanilla `Object` object? (If its a jquery plugin the key is [returning `.each`](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#using-the-each-method))

Comment: On a personal level it's not relevant, I'd like to know how to do both (especially the vanilla extension because I won't always have jQuery). For this particular question, I've done it this way and I do have access to a jQuery library the page.

Comment: @Snsa90: As you seem to concern yourself with DOM elements, you will want to use a jQuery plugin (`$.fn.myMethod`). There are no elements in a generic `Object` method. Regarding your question, jQuery doesn't distinguish single elements, it's always a collection.

Comment: But its not relevant to the case of a vanilla `Object` - there is only ever one object. The fact that a jQuery selector returns an "object" is a side-effect of javascript.

Comment: @Bergi - that approach could be useful - thanks.

Comment: @Jamiec - yeah, to explain myself a bit better - can this approach even be used in my case ? is there a way to rewrite this so that (we're talking vanilla here) I can select multiple elements and apply the method? Am I taking the wrong approach completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing two very different, albeit slightly related, concepts

- Authoring of jquery plugins, which can act on multiple selected elements
- Adding properties/methods to the prototype of an existing object's prototype

As you seem to be concerned with DOM manipulation i'll show how to do both.

---

### jQuery

The scope of writing jQuery plugins is *vast* but you should start with the basic [guide to authoring plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). You essentially add your methods to `$.fn` and then they work as per all other jQuery methods. As you know, a jQuery selector can select many elements, and you handle this situation by returning `this.each` from the plugin

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    return this.each(function() {
        // Do something to each element here.
    });

};
```

usage: `$(".myElements").myPlugin();`

### Vanilla

If you're selecting multiple elements using vanilla javascript you're probably using one of `getElementsByName` or `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`. You would need to add your new method to the return type of these methods -  that would be `NodeList` - and you could enumerate it within the `value` in the normal way

```
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, 'myMethod', {
    enumerable : false,
    configurable: true,
    value : function(args) {
        var _self = this;
        console.log(_self.length); // should be the number of elements
        return this
    }
});
```

usage: `document.getElementsByName("something").myMethod();` or `document.querySelectorAll("a").mymethod();`

Comment: Thanks - exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `$('.elements').each()` function and repeat it for every element.

```
$('.elements').each(function() {
    $(this).myMethod() );
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't quite work I believe. I'd like to know "the proper" way of doing it.

Comment: Stray bracket: ')', also, this isn;t explaining anything and it doesn't help the question as its not about 'how do I execute the function on every element'...